# Why did Hagrid disguise his wand segments in a conspicuous bright pink umbrella?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

We know that Hagrid had his wand snapped after being accused of opening the Chamber of Secrets.

We know that Hadrid's wand segments were contained within a bright pink umbrella.

We can assume he was trying to hide his wand from the Ministry of Magic.

Surely if Hagrid was seen carrying a bright, pink, flowery umbrella, presumably with some sort of wooden pole or shaft - in all weather conditions, rain or shine - then anyone with half a brain would assume that it contained parts of a wand, or at the very least it would have some magic ability.

If Hagrid wanted to truly hide the fragments of his wand, surely something more inconspicuous would have been appropriate?

Comment: Hidden in plain sight

Comment: @Valorum There is a significant difference between hiding in plain sight and drawing attention in a suspicious way! Regularly carrying a bright pink umbrella indoors, during the summer is not considered hidden in plain sight!

Comment: Parasols are quite fashionable, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Hagrid always having his "disguised" wand on himself doesn't mean he always keeps it in his hand [*]; in this, he behaves just as every other wizard would do.
The pockets in Hagrid's moleskin overcoat are either big enough or magically extended to store the umbrella and keep it out of sight.

> “I’m on it, Harry, don’ worry!” Hagrid yelled, and **from inside his jacket pocket** he pulled his flowery pink umbrella.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deatly Hallows*, chapter 4 *The Seven Potters*</sub>

I did not double-check every instance of the umbrella being cited in the books, but I have the impression they usually fell into one of these cases:

- while facing **dangerous situations** in which the presence of MoM officers is unlikely, and anyway his secret being discovered would really be the lesser evil that could occur Hagrid;
- when a little magic could quickly solve **a problem with muggles** (for example when he deals with the Dursleys).

Moreover, we are told several times that the wizards' understanding of muggles' fashion and customs is scarce; so, while Harry (and the reader) finds the pink umbrella in the hand of a (half) giant conspicuous, a wizard would probably just find it quaint *just for being a muggle object*.

[*] A lot of time was spent trying to phrase this without any double entendre, but all efforts were in vain.

Comment: True, I hadn't thought of the fact that being half giant, he could easily conceal it in his clothes. However, we are discussing a 50 year period. Anyone that spent any time in Hogwarts would have seen Hagrid with this umbrella. You are correct about the uses (see full list in next comment) however it still doesn't defend the bad choice of disguise!

Comment: Unsuccessful Magic: Hagrid tried to transfigure Dudley Dursley into a pig, Hagrid tried to repair the sidecar of Sirius Black's motorcycle, but instead destroyed it completely.
Successful magic: Hagrid made fire in the fireplace at Hut-on-the-Rock. Hagrid made the row boat that him and Harry Potter were using to get back to the mainland go faster by tapping it twice on the side. Hagrid used his umbrella to gain access to Diagon Alley, twice. Hagrid insinuated to Harry that he had used magic to enlarge the pumpkins to the size of boulders. Hagrid successfully cast the Aguamenti Charm.

Comment: Regarding muggle fashion, there are numerous references to umbrellas in the magic world. Including the Umbrella stand that Tonks trips over at 12 Grimmauld Place in Order of the Pheonix Chapter 4. The same umbrella stand is mentioned in Deathly Hallows Chapter 9.

Comment: After using www.potter-search.com I can see countless more uses of umbrellas by wizards. Like this usage in PoA "But it was considerably more than a bit of rain. Such was the popularity of Quidditch that the whole school turned out to watch the match as usual, but they ran down the lawns toward the Quidditch field, heads bowed against the ferocious wind, umbrellas being whipped out of their hands as they went. Just before he entered the locker room, Harry saw Malfoy, Crabbe, and Goyle, laughing and pointing at him from under an enormous umbrella on their way to the stadium."

Comment: I understand the first line. Just because Hagrid has magic in his rod, that doesn't mean that he is always gripping it. Sometimes he hides it in his clothing.